# Launch a fancybox pop up from another

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Is this possible? With default options it looks like it isnt.

Update
I actually want one fancybox on top of the other. If I use the fancybox() method in another fancybox, it closes the earlier fancybox. Is there a way to launch one fb on top of another?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can - **if the parent fancybox is in iframe mode** it will work. But i have not yet found a solution if the parent is inline-content...anyone?